How to communicate across network segments?
I have two hosts, A and B, which are connected to the same router via Ethernet.
A's IP address is 192.168.3.100, but I don't know B's IP address.
I want to scan B's IP address through A, but B's network segment is not 192.168.3, its network segment may be 192.168.10 or 192.168.12.
I want to scan B's IP address through A, but B's network segment is not 192.168.3, and I don't know B's network segment.
How do I get B's IP?

What do you know about B? How would you distinguish it in scan results from some other host?

To answer your question with the information given: You don't.

@grawity_u1686 B is a network camera. The router is only connected to two machines, A and B. So as long as the IP can be scanned, it must be B's IP.
